# Split big query to google maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have a table with over million locations

- id
- address
- longitude
- latitude

User can enter an address and he gets the nearest locations by 5km radius in google map.

My select query :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat1.") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(".$lng1.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat1.") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM star HAVING distance < ".$rad." ORDER BY distance");
```

results on table, inside javascript <>

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "    
   var marker".$row{'id'}." = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(".$row{'lat'}." , ".$row{'lng'}."),
    map: map
    });
    var infowindow".$row{'id'}." = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'City : ".$row{'city'}.", Address : ".$row{'address'}." , Lat : ".$row{'lat'}." , Lng : ".$row{'lng'}."'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker".$row{'id'}.", 'click', function() {
    infowindow".$row{'id'}.".open(map, marker".$row{'id'}.");
    });
    ";
}
```

My problem is when it gets over 10 locations, its doesn't show the google map.. I dont want to use LIMIT 0,10, I wanna show all the results.

**How do I split the query to search each time 10% from the big table?**

Something lke putting the markers on runtime after the page loads.

Comment: are you getting an error? What does your JS console say when you try and retrieve over 10 locations?

Comment: no error, the JS code is in the source code of the page, but there is no map showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for clarifying. Here is my edited answer.

The problem seems to be that you want an efficient way to break up the results of a query into smaller parts, without having to re-query the database. In the example you provided, the location-based query would produce a list of 10,000 results, whose results you'd like to further sub0divide into 10 chunks of 1,000 each, without going back to the database. I presume this is because the original query which returned 10,000 results is slow to begin with, and querying for results 1,000 at a time would be equally slow.

There are several potential solutions to this problem, and which one you choose would depend on how the data is used in the application. Is this query unique to a single user of your application, or is a different variation of it used by tens, hundreds, or thousands of users?

If you have the same query being used by all the users of your application, then I would select the results of the entire query into a (quasi-)temporary table, using a cron job. This table would solely exist to store cached data. As you page through the results, 1,000 at a time, you would query the cached table. This would be much faster, because all the distances would be pre-calculated, and you would not have to run the haversine formula again.

If many variations of the same query are being used by all the users of your application, you could also store the entire results of the query as a serialized array in the user's session. Then, each time you need to go through the results, 1,000 at a time, you would read from the ordered array stored in the session, and produce the appropriate results.

If you're facing thousands, or millions of variations of this query, across your entire application, then the best way to make it faster, would be to rethink either how/where the data is stored, and/or how you access it. I know that this option may be not be feasible in the short term, but sometimes such changes are required to produce dramatic changes in efficiency. I hope that helps somewhat!

Comment: As you can see in my question's example, my select SQL sentence gets the results, it checks every id in the big table to see if the location is in 5km radius from the given address, I want to make it more scalable, how do I edit my code to search each time 10% of the table, and when the pages turns on show the results from the 10% and then in runtime search 10% at the time, something like : Table with id from 1 to 10,000, Page loads > show the nearest locations for id 1 to 1000 on the google map, After that on runtime add to the map the results from id:1001 to id:2000

Comment: Hi Jim, I've edited my original answer. I hope it's more helpful.

Comment: First of all thank you Jay Sheth ! I have a random locations in a table so can't change that, I just think that query 1,000 each time and check it with jQuery will be faster then checking all 10,000 with MySql , still have no idea how to do that after that page loads.. reading and tryin' to follow this tut now : http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Something lke putting the markers on runtime after the page loads**

A simple way to do this would expose the search functionality through an http endpoint and query that using AJAX, instead of reloading a page with the results

```
# search.php

$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$locations = search_for_close_locations($lat, $lng);
echo json_encode($locations);
```

---

```
# your_page.js
// attache event handler to the lat/lng input
$('#lat_lng_input_form').submit(function() {
  $.getJSON('/search.php', function(response) {
     // clear all previous markers 
     // place new markers
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please show or link to an example of this simple way?

Answer (score 0):

My Failed try#1 : 
Tried to select each time 1000 records from the big table, and then use JS to calculate each record if its in 5km radius and if it is, show it on the map.. and what happend is the source code grew by alot of JS..

This is in the google map initialize() function :

```
$q = "select MAX(id) from table";
$res1 = mysql_query($q);
$data1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
$max =  $data1[0];
$start = 1;
$end = 1000;
 while($end < $max) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ".$start." AND id < ".$end);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
        if(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(<?php echo $lat1." , ".$lng1." , ".$row{'lat'}." , ".$row{'lng'} ?>) < 5) {
            addMarker(<?php echo $row{'lat'}.",".$row{'lng'}; ?>);
        }
<?php
    }
    $start = $start + 1000;
    $end = $end + 1000;
```